# Having trouble accessing deployed jsp page

Tags: jsp, struts

I've been working on a JSP/struts project, right now I'm just trying to get the basic first page up and working before I begin the actual project but I'm pretty new to struts and after deploying my page in MyEclipse, I keep getting an error when trying to access the localhost page through my browser. The error I'm getting is:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report
message
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:     javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve definition for form bean userLoginForm
```

it continues from there but that's the basic message.

The initial JSP page's code is

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" prefix="html"%>

<html> 
    <head>
        <title>JSP for UserLoginForm form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <html:form action="/userLogin">
            userName : <html:text property="userName"/><html:errors         property="userName"/><br/>
            enter : <html:text property="enter"/><html:errors property="enter"/>    <br/>
            server : <html:text property="server"/><html:errors     property="server"/><br/>
            password : <html:text property="password"/><html:errors     property="password"/><br/>
            <html:submit/><html:cancel/>
        </html:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The xml file this works with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration     1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">

<struts-config>
  <data-sources />
  <form-beans >
    <form-bean name="UserLoginForm" type="strutsPackage.struts.form.UserLoginForm" />

  </form-beans>

  <global-exceptions />
  <global-forwards />
  <action-mappings >
    <action
      attribute="userLoginForm"
      input="/login.jsp"
      name="userLoginForm"
      path="/userLogin"
      scope="request"
      type="strutsPackage.struts.action.UserLoginAction">
      <forward name="failure" path="/login.jsp" />
      <forward name="success" path="/login.jsp" />
    </action>

  </action-mappings>

  <message-resources parameter="strutsPackage.struts.ApplicationResources" />
</struts-config>
```

and the action page is:

```
package strutsPackage.struts.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    /** 
 * MyEclipse Struts
 * Creation date: 04-18-2013
 * 
 * XDoclet definition:
 * @struts.action path="/userLogin" name="userLoginForm" input="/login.jsp"     scope="request" validate="true"
 * @struts.action-forward name="failure" path="/login.jsp"
 * @struts.action-forward name="success" path="/login.jsp"
 */
public class UserLoginAction extends Action {
    /*
     * Generated Methods
     */

    /** 
         * Method execute
         * @param mapping
     * @param form
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @return ActionForward
     */
    public ActionForward execute( 
              ActionMapping mapping, 
                  ActionForm form, 
              HttpServletRequest request, 
              HttpServletResponse response) { 
              UserLoginForm userLoginForm = (UserLoginForm) form; 

              if(userLoginForm.getUserName().equals("myeclipse") &&     userLoginForm.getPassword().equals("myeclipse")) 
              { 
               request.setAttribute("userName", userLoginForm.getUserName()); 
               return mapping.findForward("success"); 
              } 

              return mapping.findForward("failure"); 
             }
}
```

Every once and a while I'll get a different error page that says

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at     line 10

7:      <title>JSP for UserLoginForm form</title>
8:  </head>
9:  <body>
10:         <html:form action="/userLogin">
11:             userName : <html:text property="userName"/><html:errors     property="userName"/><br/>
12:             enter : <html:text property="enter"/><html:errors property="enter"/><br/>
13:             server : <html:text property="server"/><html:errors property="server"/><br/>
```

These errors seem to interchange for not apparent reason, but what is really confusing me is that I got the page to show up fine yesterday, didn't touch it anymore and today when I tried to open it, I got the first error page. I've tried redeploying the site but I'm still getting the same thing.

So I don't know if this is a problem with my code or with my version of Tomcat, or if something is wrong with my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`"userLoginForm"` as in your action mapping is not the same as `"UserLoginForm"` as in your form bean definition. They need to be the same.

Also, it's not clear if you're actually *using* XDoclet; if you are, you need to say as much, since it generates various configuration artifacts.

Unrelated: unless you have a good reason, don't bother learning Struts 1. It's ancient, it's EOLed, and should never be used for new development. Struts 2 or Spring MVC are typical replacements, or you can move to JSF, Play, Grails, JRuby on Rails, etc. if you're tied to the JVM.

Comment: Now *there's* an odd downvote; love it when there's a vendetta.